# What is the difference between Eclipse and Myeclipse

Tags: eclipse, difference, myeclipse

I want to develop java dynamic web application that make use of struts2 and hibernate.

I am familiar with Eclipse but new to MyEclipse. Both IDEs looks same if compared with UI. What are the features of Myeclipse ?

Which IDE will be better option to develop the web application ?

Thanks.

Comment: MyEclipse is a commercial product that extends the tools provided in Eclipse.  MyEclipse will make web development easier.  Read the [MyEclipse feature page](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/features/) to see what features MyEclipse has.

Answer (score 7):

As Gilbert writes, MyEclipse extends and integrates tools from both MyEclipse projects and other projects, as well as extra functionality developed in-house, within the MyEclipse package. It can provide a cheap alternative to IBM's Rational Application Developer (RAD), for WebSphere developers who don't need the full power of RAD but need more than the free eclipse based solutions. It's inexpensive for the basic and professional versions and can be trialled for 30 days, free.

Comment: RAD == Rapid Application Development or Rational Application Developer?

Comment: The latter. RAD=Rational Application Developer. Will edit.